# Retrieve android parse column and set it to array

Tags: android, parsing, textview

I have a table in Parse which is named Customer_Information. And there is a column named username. I want to retrieve all the values in the username column and store it to array. After storing, i want to set it to a single textview. Is this possible? I've tried this code but it has an error ArrayIndexOutOfBounds.

```
public class Users extends Activity{

    private static final String tbname = "Customer_Information";
    private static final String uname = "username";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.users);

    TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery(tbname);{

    try{
            List<ParseObject> test = query.find();
            for(int x=0;x<test.size();x++){
            String[] str = {test.get(x).getString(uname)};
            text.setText("Username: "+str[x]+"\n");
            }
    }
    catch (com.parse.ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is most likely with this line:

```
text.setText("Username: "+str[x]+"\n");
```

You are trying to access an index, but you are accessing it with `x`. If all the `ParseObject`s return an array of the *same* length, after a while, as `x` increases, it will become greater than that array's greatest index, resulting in an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

I suggest you first do some testing: print out the values of `str`, figure out what index you need, then change the line so it uses the *constant* index. Based on the fact that you only have 1 element in the array since you do

```
String[] str = {test.get(x).getString(uname)};//one element array
```

the index is most likely `0`:

```
text.setText("Username: "+str[0]+"\n");
```

If you are not going to make `str` any larger than 1 element, discard it and use just a single `String`.

Comment: yes you are right, sorry for my mistake. But how can i put the values of the uname column into an array? i cant figure out how to put it into an array string thats why i tried the     String[] str = {test.get(x).getString(uname)};

Comment: @kdot You should probably be using an `List` for this. Just declare it outside the loop, then inside call `add()` on the `List` with the String. It really depends what exactly you want to do.